# Custom fields are not restored to previous revisions

Tags: custom-field

I have built several Wordpress websites and noticed that custom fields are not restored to previous revisions. This might cause a problem when using custom fields to store content. Anybody knows how to add the custom fields to the revision history?

Comment: Two things: 1) This plugin: https://github.com/adamsilverstein/wp-post-meta-revisions 2) This plugin: http://pastebin.com/LMwEush4 The first one enables custom meta fields to be saved at revision time. The second one gives you a nice admin screen to select which custom meta fields will trigger a revision.

Answer (score 2):

Post revisions are for the fields in the posts database table and not the postmeta database  table.

So if you want to create your own postmeta revision you could save the meta when the revision is made using `_wp_put_post_revision` and you can restore the meta using `wp_restore_post_revision`.

Comment: Doesn't _wp_put_post_revision save only post data (title, content)? It uses _wp_post_revision_fields which doesn't check for custom fields? My goal is to be able to restore the custom fields to any point in the history of the post, as in the revisions of the title and content.

Comment: @Tomer, that is exactly what i'm saying `_wp_put_post_revision` saves only post fields and not post meta (custom fields), so to save your custom fields before a post revision is created you can hook to the `_wp_put_post_revision` hook and save your the custom fields you want, and when you restore a revision you can use `wp_restore_post_revision` to restore those saved fields as well